# Problem with installing Laravel/ui in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-8, laravel-ui

Im trying to install laravel/ui but I get this error:

```
**Problem 1**
- laravel/tinker is locked to version v2.5.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- laravel/tinker v2.5.0 requires illuminate/console ^8.0 -> found illuminate/console[v8.0.0, ...,     8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  **Problem 2**
- laravel/ui[v3.0.0, ..., 3.x-dev] require illuminate/console ^8.0 -> found illuminate/console[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/ui ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v3.0.0, v3.1.0, 3.x-dev].
```

I tried:

```
composer require laravel/ui "^3.0" --dev
```

and also:

```
composer require laravel/ui  --dev
```

I always get the same error.

NB: Im using the latests version: Laravel 8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update manually `composer.json` file to have:

```
"laravel/framework": "^8.12",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
"laravel/ui": "^3.0",
```

in it.

Run `composer update` to update packages to latest

Comment: you can also run command `composer require laravel/ui:^3.0 --dev`

Answer (score 12):

just write

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

then if you have a problem ,update dependencies by

```
 composer update
```

Comment: Perfect answer!