# Auth is not creating in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i use this command

> composer require laravel/ui

to make auth in laravel:8 but it gives the following error:

```
Using version ^3.3 for laravel/ui
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/ui
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
 - laravel/ui[v3.3.0, ..., 3.x-dev] require illuminate/console ^8.42 -> found  
  illuminate/console[v8.42.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it    
  conflicts with another require.
 - Root composer.json requires laravel/ui ^3.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v3.3.0, 3.x-dev].


 Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: run `composer require laravel/ui "^3.3"` as the error suggests.

Comment: @MohsenNazari   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/ui 3.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v3.3.0].
    - laravel/ui v3.3.0 requires illuminate/console ^8.42 -> found illuminate/console[v8.42.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: try an older version like `composer require laravel/ui:^3.2` or `composer require laravel/ui:^2.5`

Comment: While laravel/ui continues to work with the latest version of Laravel, you should consider using Laravel Breeze for new projects. Or, for something more robust, consider Laravel Jetstream. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446578/problem-with-installing-laravel-ui-in-laravel-8

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should update all your packages of php using this command:

```
composer update
```

after this try with the install of laravel/ui:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

execute one of them :
// Generate login / registration scaffolding...

```
 php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
 php artisan ui vue --auth
 php artisan ui react --auth
```

finally

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Update manually **composer.json** file

```
"laravel/framework": "^8.12",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
"laravel/ui": "^3.0",
```

Then run `composer update` Command